# Will a Nikon AF-S TC-17E II teleconverter work with a 70–300 AF lens on my D3400?

Tags: nikon, teleconverter

Will a Nikon AF-S TC-17E II Teleconverter adapter work on my D3400 with 70-300 AF lens?

Answer (score 5):

The TC will work with the camera. But the D3400 has no AF drive motor, and a TC will not add that either... so it would be manual focus only.

Additionally, the TC has a blocking tab that prevents it from being mounted on lenses not on the compatibility list. But if that tab is removed it will mount, and work, with *some lenses* not on the list. For example, I use them on my 24mm PC-E lens. And they work on my 28-300; but that is pointless as magnifying a soft image only makes it softer.

However, if the TC is modified and installed onto a lens with a moving rear element, or not enough space, damage can occur. I don't think the rear element is an issue with the 70-300AF, but it has a baffled exit pupil so I don't know if the TC could mount. If instead you meant the 70-300 AF-P, then it will not mount for certain; that lens has a flush mounted rear element.

You could get a Kenko (or other brand) TC which does not have the protruding element to get around that issue. But the whole idea of using TC's on the 70-300AF is rather moot, it's really not very good at the long end anyway. And the AF-P version is not that much better... much like my 28-300.

Answer (score 3):

Nikon's [AF-S Teleconverter Compatibility](https://www.nikonusa.com/Assets/Common-Assets/Images/Teleconverter-Compatibility/EN_Comp_chart.html) list doesn't list either that camera or lens, so I'd say no.

Comment: Even stronger than "so I'd say no", the compatibility list states at the top: _NIKKOR lenses not listed cannot be used with the AF-S Teleconverters. The rear elements of NIKKOR lenses not listed can contact and damage the Teleconverter element and must not be attached._